# Can't get the specific user information to be displayed on the page in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, project, jsonplaceholder

I have come across the problem, namely I cannot get the program to display the info of the specific user when clicking on it. The best I could manage is the displaying of every user together. Can you help me with this problem?

Here is the code:

service.ts :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@ Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class JSONPlaceholderpostsService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getData():Observable<any> {
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
return this.http.get<any>(url)}}
```

The Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JSONPlaceholderpostsService } from 'src/app/posts/jsonplaceholderposts.service';

@ Component({
selector: 'app-userinfo',
templateUrl: './userinfo.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./userinfo.component.css']})

export class UserinfoComponent implements OnInit {
data:Array<any>

constructor(private JSONPlaceholder: JSONPlaceholderpostsService,){

this.data = new Array<any>()}

ngOnInit(): void {this.getUserInfoFromAPI()}

getUserInfoFromAPI(){
this.JSONPlaceholder.getData().subscribe((data) => {
console.log(data)this.data = data})}
```

And the component.html file:

```
<p>USER INFO</p>

<ul *ngFor="let element of data">
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{element.id}}</button></li>
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{element.name}}</button></li>
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{element.email}}</button></li>
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{element.adress}}</button></li>
</ul>

<button ><a hrer="#" routerLink="/userposts" routerLinkActive="actvie">POSTS</a></button>
```

Thank you all in advance

what I want to happen is that instead of the list of every user just the specific user info to be displayed.

Comment: so what you want is "when the user click on a user the list of the user disappear and only this user show" ?

Comment: So basically when I enter the abovementioned page, I get the list of all the users. I need to get only one insted of all. I hope that helped you understand my problem

Comment: what do you use to choose the specific user you need ?! do you have the id for the user you want or anything to identify the user when you get to this page ?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I was told to do three things. on the first page there should be a list of users. That was no problem. The second was that when you push the user button you should get the user info and the posts button. Then when you push the posts button you should get the posts of that persons posts

Comment: I'll provide the stackblitz link to make it easier to understand:     https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jqhjqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuserposts%2Fuserposts.component.ts

Comment: ok I think i got it

Comment: Do you think you could help? It would mean a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first thing i found 
`[routerLink]="['/userinfo/ + obj.name']"` i think you mean `[routerLink]="['/userinfo', d.name]"`

Comment: can anything else be done? what else do I need to change?

Comment: is the solution is not clear or are you facing any problems?

Comment: One Moment I'll check if everythingwokrs on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here how I may make it work

for the route I will use the id instead of the name

```
{path: 'userinfo/:id', component: UserinfoComponent}
```

and then for useInfo, I will take the user id from the route and filter the list to to get the user and then use this user

Html

```
    <p>USER INFO</p>

<ul >
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{user.id}}</button></li>
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{user.name}}</button></li>
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{user.email}}</button></li>
<li><button (click)="getUserInfoFromAPI()">{{user.adress}}</button></li>
</ul>

<button ><a hrer="#" routerLink="/userposts" routerLinkActive="actvie">POSTS</a></button>
```

and ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JSONPlaceholderpostsService } from '../posts/jsonplaceholderposts.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-userinfo',
  templateUrl: './userinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userinfo.component.css'],
})
export class UserinfoComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any = '';

  constructor(private JSONPlaceholder: JSONPlaceholderpostsService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserInfoFromAPI();
  }

  getUserInfoFromAPI() {
    this.JSONPlaceholder.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      const userID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || "";

      [this.user] = data.filter((user) => user.id == userID);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you run `npm install` and rerun the server

Comment: It stopped giving me all the users info but now I get bank buttons. Can you explain what can I do to fill these spaces?

Comment: just use this line instead 
` [this.user] = data.filter((user) => user.id == userID);`
it was returing any array of length 1 and you need the object inside the array

Comment: here a link with a working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jqhjqc-nxpk2o?file=src/app/userinfo/userinfo.component.ts